# python34 installing rtree on Windows 64

Tags: python

I am using windows10 64 bits, my os.name is 'nt', I used pip to  install but its complaining about the spatialindex_c.dll

```
File "C:\Users\Bachir\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-td64lrth\rtree\rtree\core.py", line 101, in <module> raise OSError("could not find or load spatialindex_c.dll") 
OSError: could not find or load spatialindex_c.dll
```

I downloaded rtree-0.8.2 and then run python setup.py install and I have the same message

```
PS C:\Users\Bachir\documents\Python Scripts\Rtree-0.8.2> python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    import rtree
  File "C:\Users\Bachir\documents\Python Scripts\Rtree-0.8.2\rtree\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .index import Rtree
  File "C:\Users\Bachir\documents\Python Scripts\Rtree-0.8.2\rtree\index.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\Bachir\documents\Python Scripts\Rtree-0.8.2\rtree\core.py", line 101, in <module>
    raise OSError("could not find or load spatialindex_c.dll")
OSError: could not find or load spatialindex_c.dll
PS C:\Users\Bachir\documents\Python Scripts\Rtree-0.8.2>
```

I donwloaded the spatialindex dll files ' libspatialindex-1.8.1-win-msvc-2010-x64-x32.zip ' . this file contain both 32  and 64 bits ,  unzip and put in the installation folder, when installing using python setuo.py install it still complaining about the spatialindex dll file